# Odbc connection with Sqlserver Progress openEdge

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am working on the MS SQL server so I want to connect MS SQL Server to progress OpenEdge Database and import all data from OpenEdge to SQL Server through ODBC. I add driver from Data sources in administrator tools but don't know next step that how i will connect to OpenEdge from MS Sql Server? How can I achieve this target? Please help me.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? Can you include what have you tried so far, what commands did you run, etc?

Comment: @kenorb I add driver of ODBC from Data sources in administrator tools but don't know next step that how i will connect to OpenEdge from MS Sql Server?